# Need help querying distinct combinations of nested fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

**Desired result**

I am trying to query my collection and obtain every unique combination of a batch and entry code. I don't care about anything other than these fields, the parent objects do not matter to me.

**What I have tried**

I tried running:

`db.accountant_ledgers.aggregate( [ {"$group": { "_id": { entryCode: "$actions.entry.entryCode", batchCode: "$actions.entry.batchCode" } } } ]);`

**Problem**

I get unexpected results when I run that query. I'm looking for a list of every unique combination of batch and entry codes, but instead I get a list of arrays? Perhaps these are the results I'm looking for, but I have no idea how to read them if they are.

**Theory**

I think perhaps this could have to do with the fact that these fields are nested. Each object has several actions, each action has several entries. <del>I believe that the result from that query is just the aggregated entry and batch codes found in each object. I don't know how long the list of results is, but I'd guess it's the same number as the total number of objects in my collection (~90 million).</del>

EDIT: I found out that there are only 182 results from my query, which is clearly significantly smaller than 90 million. My new theory is that it has found all unique objects, with the criteria for "uniqueness" being the list of the batch and entry codes that appear in their actions, which makes sense. There should be a lot of repetition in the collection.

**Question**

How can I achieve the result I'm looking for? I'm expecting something like:

```
FEE, MG
EXN, WT
ACH, 9C
```

...etc

**Notes**

I apologize if this is a bad question, I'm not sure how else to frame it. Let me know if I can improve my question at all.

Picture below shows the results of the query.

[image]

**EDIT FOR ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

I can't share any sample documents, but the general structure of the data is shown (crudely) in the below image. Each Entity has several Actions, each Action has one Entry and each Entry has one Batch code and one Entry code.

List item[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *are* getting a list of documents (each is a map or a hash), not a list of arrays.

The GUI you are using is trying to show you the contents of each document on the top level which is maybe what is confusing.

If you run the query in `mongo` shell you should see a list of documents.

It looks like your *inputs* are documents where entry code and batch code are arrays, if so:

- Edit your question to include sample documents you are querying **as text**
- You could use $unwind to flatten those arrays before using $group.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I edited my question to show the structure of the inputs I'm working with. Entry code and Batch code are strings, but they are contained within a structure that belongs to an array. 

I'm looking into whether $unwind will help me, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: `db.accountant_ledgers.aggregate( [ {"$unwind": "$actions"}, {"$group": { "_id": { entryCode: "$actions.entry.entryCode", batchCode: "$actions.entry.batchCode" } } } ])` was the winning query!